nginx configuration variables not evaluating
I'm setting up an nginx 1.27 configuration for several subdomains that will share a lot of similar configuration, so I was trying to use variables, but they don't seem to be expanding/evaluating.
foo.bar.com.conf:
server {
  set $subdomain foo;
  include common_config;
}

common_config:
listen 80
server_name $subdomain.bar.com;
root /www/bar.com/public_html;
access_log /www/bar.com/logs/$subdomain.access.log;
error_log /www/bar.com/logs/$subdomain.error.log;

A run of nginx -t says everything is good, and I'm expecting to see:
/www/bar.com/logs/foo.error.log
but instead I see the error log initialized as:
/www/bar.com/logs/$subdomain.error.log
I've tried surrounding the configuration in quotes, and using ${variable} syntax, like this:
error_log "/www/bar.com/logs/${subdomain}.error.log";

...but that just produces a file:
/www/bar.com/logs/${subdomain}.error.log
I have a different server entry on the same nginx instance where variables seem to work fine:
if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
  set $year $1;
  set $month $2;
  set $day $3;
}
access_log = /workingdomain.com/logs/access-$year-$month-$day.log;

...and this works fine. I get /workingdomain.com/logs/access-2024-07-29.log, for example.
In case there was some issue with variables like $subdomain not passing from one config file to another included config file, I tried hardcoding the variable into the common_config, and it still failed.
I must be missing something simple, but I need another pair of eyes.

I'm not entirely sure, but I think it may have to do with your set $subdomain foo being out of scope/the function block. I did some NGINX stuff ages ago and remember something to do with map to declare out of scope variables.

You can have a look on map module :http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

You can't use variables in server_name directive. Not all directives accept variables. E.g. in access_log it's written clearly "The file path can contain variables (0.7.6+)"
